# Fetch string from arrays, which does not contain duplicate characters

Tags: java

```
String[] arr = {"kolkata", "delhi", "pune", "mumbai"}
```

Can any one help me out with java code to fetch a string from given array, where string should not contain any duplicate characters.

Output from above array should be "pune" and "delhi".

```
String[] arr = {"kolkata", "mumbai", "pune", "delhi"};


    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){

        String name = arr[i];
        char[] ch = name.toCharArray();
        boolean flag = false;

        for (int j=0; j < ch.length; j++){

            for (int k=0; k < ch.length; k++){
                if (ch[j] != ch[k]){
                    flag = true;
                    //break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (flag){
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far? Usually when asking these homework / assignment types of questions, you should show that you actually put some effort into the task yourself, and that you are not just dumping it here for your convenience. Also see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822).

Comment: This looks like homework or a learning exercise so _you_ should come up with the code. We can help with specifics but won't do the work for you. Ask yourself: how would you test whether a string contains duplicate characters? How do you filter those strings when "fetching" the elements from the array?

Comment: @maloomeister
Should we answer or not for this type of questions?

Comment: @manikantanvsr Excerpt from the linked meta post above: "_It's usually better not to provide a complete code sample if you believe it would not help the student, using your best judgment._" And also relevant: [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166).

Comment: Added the code snippet, which I tried to solve the problem but the code is not giving expected result. Can anyone please help me out what's I am doing wrong in above code?

Answer (score 0):

Process each string in the array to compare the length of the string with the count of district characters in it. There are many ways to do this. One of the ways is as shown below:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] arr = { "kolkata", "delhi", "pune", "mumbai" };
        Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(s -> System.out.println(s + " has duplicate characters => " + hasDuplicateChars(s)));
    }

    static boolean hasDuplicateChars(String s) {
        return s.chars().distinct().count() != s.length();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
kolkata has duplicate characters => true
delhi has duplicate characters => false
pune has duplicate characters => false
mumbai has duplicate characters => true
```